# Set Select value of dropdown list in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I have a table that has 4 columns and column 4 is a dropdown list.

I know how to set the value in a normal Select -- but NOT when it's a Table field.

```
var $td = $('#Tbl_LD tbody td');
var vtd;
 var Fidx = 3;

var SelectVal = '2';

 vtd = $td.eq((Fidx*4)+3);

 vtd.val(SelectVal);    // my attempt at setting the Table row 3 field 4 select option to 2 -- does not work
```

My attempt at setting the Table row 3 field 4 select option to 2 -- does not work

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable name should be clear and human understandable. Now regarding your problem, better to do like this:

```
var rows = $('#Tbl_LD tbody tr');
var selectVal = '2';

var rows3 = rows.eq(2);
var row3col4 = row3.find('td').eq(3);
var selectEl = row3col4.find('select');

// or club all selector in single line
// selectEl = rows.eq(2).find('td').eq(3).find('select');

selectEl.val(SelectVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

> My attempt at setting the Table row 3 field 4 select option to 2 -- does not work

In this case you need to use `:eq()` on both the `tr` and `td` to target the `select` relevant cell. Something like this:

```
$('#Tbl_LD tbody tr:eq(2) td:eq(3) select').val(SelectVal);
```

Comment: The table is already displayed.  Fidx is the table row to update and V is a string that equals the select value I want.  The following is execute and the table shows no changes.  $('#Tbl_LD tbody tr:eq(Fidx) td:eq(3) select').val(V);

Comment: Well yes, you need to concatenate the values

Comment: ```$(`#Tbl_LD tbody tr:eq(${Fidx}) td:eq(3) select`).val(SelectVal);``` or `$('##Tbl_LD tbody tr').eq(Fidx).find('td').eq(3).find('select').val(SelectVal);`